# Weighted Least Squares vs Monte Carlo comparison

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, montecarlo, least-squares

I have an experimental dataset of the following values (y, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, w), where y is the measured quantity, x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> are the two independet variables and w is the error of each measurement.
The function I've chosen to describe my data is 
[image]

#### These are my tasks:

1) Estimate values of b<sub>i</sub> 
2) Estimate their standard errors 
3) Calculate predicted values of *f*(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>) on a mesh grid and estimate their confidence intervals 
4) Calculate predicted values of 
[image] and definite integral [image]

and their confidence intervals on a mesh grid

#### I have several questions:

1) Can all of my tasks be solved by weighted least squares? I've solved task 1-3 using WLS in matrix form by linearisation of the chosen function, but I have no idea, how to solve step №4.

2) I've performed Monte Carlo simulations to estimate *b<sub>i</sub>* and their s.e. I've generated perturbated values y'<sub>i</sub> from normal distribution with mean y<sub>i</sub> and standard deviation w<sub>i</sub>. I did this operation N=5000 times. For each perturbated dataset I estimated b'<sub>i</sub>, and from 5000 values of b'<sub>i</sub> I calculated mean values and their standard distribution. In the end, b<sub>i</sub> estimated from Monte-Carlo simulation coincide with those found by WLS. Am I correct, that standard deviations of b'<sub>i</sub> must be devided by № of Degrees of freedom to obtain standard error?

3) How to estimate confidence bands for predicted values of y using Monte-Carlo approach? I've generated a bunch of perturbated b<sub>i</sub> values from normal distribution using their BLUE as mean and standard deviations. Then I calculated lots of predicted values of *f(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>)*, found their means and standard deviations. Values of *f(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>)* found by WLS and MC coincide, but s.d. found from MC are 5-45 order higher than those from WLS. What is the scaling factor that I'm missing here?

4) It seems that some of parameters b are not independent of each other, since there are only 2 independent variables. Should I take this into account in question 3, when I generate b<sub>i</sub> values? If yes, how can this be done? Should I use Chi-squared test to decide whether generated values of b<sub>i</sub> are suitable for further calculations, or should they be rejected?

In fact, I not only want to solve tasks I've mentioned earlier, but also I want to compare the two methods for regression analysys. I would appreciate any help and suggestions!

Comment: Very interesting, and you've already done a lot of good work. However this is off topic for SO. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, this is a polynomial regression model, and my guess is that it's possible to construct an exact solution, and any MC simulation should yield the same result as that exact solution (aside from sampling error). If MC simulation yields something different, there is a bug in MC, a bug in the exact solution, or MC as it is set up is solving a different problem from the exact solution. Good luck and have fun, it's a good problem.

Comment: Thanks! I've replicated this post on stats branch, as you suggested.

Comment: The problem with exact solution is that authors of the dataset that I am using did not provide uncertanties of x_1 and x_2. So I can't calculate exact solution in a traditional way:
s(f)^2 = (df/dx1)^2*s(x)^2 + (df/dx2)^2*s(x2)^2